# Airport Extreme 802.11ac Can't See USB HDD

Tags: network, hard-drive, usb, airport

Hardware:

- Airport Extreme 802.11ac
- Transcend StoreJet 250GB HDD
- Belkin 4-port, powered USB hub

Configuration:

- HDD formatted as MS-DOS (FAT32) via Disk Utility
- HDD connected to USB hub
- Airport Extreme connected to USB hub

Problem:
I cannot see the drive from the Airport Utility -> Disks tab.  I want to be able to do this to setup backups over the wireless network.  When I connect the HDD directly to my MBP, it auto-mounts and I can utilize it without any problems.

---

Solution:
I ended up calling Apple support and they advised that the Airport should have sufficient power for the drive.  They had me switch to a normal USB 2.0 cable instead of the Y adapter.  Further, they had me reformat (again) to Mac OS Extended (case-insensitive).  Magically, this combination works.

Comment: I do not like your configuration. Why did you do it that way? why not connecting the HDD to the Airport Extreme?

Comment: I don't like it either.  But, it's not a self-powered drive.  According to this and other threads, the power provided by the USB port is insufficient for HDDs:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3694392?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: FWIW, I've connected the HDD directly to the Airport Extreme and it doesn't work that way either.

Comment: Have you tried formatting as HSF+ instead of FAT32?

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  I think that's what it was BEFORE I formatted FAT32, but I'll give it another try.

Comment: most likely it has to do with the disk format! do you know how to fix it? if not, let me know :)

Comment: no dice.  i still cant see any partitions in airport utility.

Comment: If your airport doesn't give enough power for the hard drive, and it doesn't like your USB hub, you could try to use a separate usb power adaptor (given you've got one of these "Y-cables"). For testing purposes, you could use some laptop/computer for getting power while plugging the data end into your airport. It _could_ even work to use the USB hub as a power adaptor while not connecting it to the airport.

Comment: Good idea.  I'll grab one of my iDevice USB power adapters and give it a shot.

Comment: Didn't work.  I plugged the aux side of the USB Y cable into a USB power adapter and into the wall, and no difference. The drive has an external LED, and it's on, but again the Airport Utility doesn't see the drive.

Comment: I had a similar issue, which I described in [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91740/22953). Unfortunately, in my situation (different to yours: my AirPort is much older), I found that the drive enclosure itself was the cause of the incompatibility.

Comment: Your solution isn't that magical sorry to say. That is the answer most people here would have given ya. Glad AppleCare could help!

Comment: Please don't put answers inside your question. Answers go down below so others can vote and comment on them. Thank you for the answer though! Switching to an USB 2.0 cable was the trick that helped for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If the HDD is a 2.5' (laptop drive) that draws power from nothing else but the USB port it will never work with a USB Hub. They all share the same power source on the Airport that has a limit of 500mA. That would work with the hdd directly in the Airport but connecting an unpowered USB Hub draws around 80-100mA and the hdd is left with 400mA to start... which is too low.

I can only imagine, but i think you are using this setup to connect more than one drive to the Airport and having multiple disks shared by it. That's ok but...

For this to work you need a special USB hub known as a Powered USB hub that you can connect to the wall socket separately. This separate power adapter draws 2-2.5A of power from the wall socket to power each USB Hub port with its own 500mA thus being able to give enough current to the hdd to operate correctly.

Check this out. Notice the wall socket power adaptor.
http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/powered-usb-hub
Also try to get a decent brand so it lasts... and doesn't cause a fire or fry your hdd in the long run.

Comment: But the OP describes the hub hardware as "Belkin 4-port, **powered** USB hub"?

Comment: Yes, it is a powered hub.  No, I'm not trying to chain multiple drives.  The only reason I added the hub was because I believed that the Airport was not providing sufficient power on its own.